# Can I use custom xml namespace in ePub 3.0?

Tags: xml, xhtml, xml-namespaces, epub

An error comes out by epub which uses custom namespaces in ePubChecker. 
Is using custom namespaces in ePub 3.0 forbidden?

example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11" xmlns:customns="http://example.com">
<head></head>
<body><customns:customtag></customns:customtag></body>
</html>
```

ERROR:

> /Untitled.epub/OPS/page0.html(5,27): element "customns:customtag" not
>   allowed here; expected the element end-tag, text or element "a",
>   "abbr", "address", "area", "article", "aside", "audio", "b", "bdi",
>   "bdo", "blockquote", "br", "button", "canvas", "cite", "code",
>   "command", "datalist", "del", "details", "dfn", "div", "dl", "em",
>   "embed", "fieldset", "figure", "footer", "form", "h1", "h2", "h3",
>   "h4", "h5", "h6", "header", "hgroup", "hr", "i", "iframe", "img",
>   "input", "ins", "kbd", "keygen", "label", "map", "mark", "menu",
>   "meter", "nav", "ns1:switch", "ns1:trigger", "ns2:math", "ns3:svg",
>   "object", "ol", "output", "p", "pre", "progress", "q", "ruby", "s",
>   "samp", "script", "section", "select", "small", "span", "strong",
>   "style", "sub", "sup", "table", "textarea", "time", "u", "ul", "var",
>   "video" or "wbr" (with xmlns:ns1="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"
>   xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
>   xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

Comment: You can do it, but it's non-standard, so who knows how various readers will choose to display (or ignore) your content.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it with a Sony PRS-650. I didn't expect but it worked. The reader showed the text between the opening and closing tags.

As far as I see [Epub 2.0.1 supports namespaces](http://idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPS_2.0.1_draft.htm#Section1.3.2) and [Epub 3.0 draft does not remove this feature](http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-changes.html#sec-removals). XHTMLs are XMLs, so it could be fine but unless it's absolutely necessary I wouldn't use this feature. Maybe the firmware of other devices isn't so well tested and won't show the book.